# Gitk lower panel cannot resize

Tags: git, gitk

In gitk there are two panel, the top panel which display mostly the list of commits, and the bottom panel which shows changes in this commit. Somehow, since this week I cannot adjust the height of these two panels, like making one of them bigger/smaller. Any idea why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Maybe you don't see thin resize widget? It's between searchbars:

[image: The specific spot highlighted]

Try to change "Edit - Preferences - Use themed widgets" option and restart gitk.

Comment: I thought changing the option made a difference, but actually that's not it. Once I realized the other comment said to look at the search box, a very unintuitive location, I could resize with or without themed widgets checked.

Comment: This is a hilarious failure of GUI design.

Answer (score 25):

Just in case this was not a technical but a user issue, note that the resize line to grab is not where it should be. It's not the window line that's above "SHA1 ID:" but above the "Search" button and below the "next" and "prev" buttons. It's extremely unintuitive.

Comment: I had the same problem, and yes, I was just looking in the wrong (right?) place.

Answer (score 21):

Hover very slowly next to where the Radio Buttons for Patch and Tree are and you will see the cursor change to the resize icon.

Answer (score 4):

I'm here because I had the same problem with gitk.

[image: Screen capture of gitk]

I found that turning off the "use themed widgets" preference setting gave me subtle, but visible resize bars all over the GUI.

see the attached screenshot.